# Using structures to find the GCD of a fraction (Simple C program)

Tags: c, structure, greatest-common-divisor

As the title says, I'm making a program to find the GCD of a fraction. The program has a function that find it, but I had run into some problems.

I want the function to accept two structure variables (denominator and numerator) and returns the GCD (integer)

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct fraction{
    int numerator,denominator;
};

int find_gcd(struct fraction s1, struct fraction s1);

int main(void)
{
    struct fraction d1;
    int gcd;

    d1.numerator= 20;
    d1.denominator= 100;

    printf("Fraction: %d/%d\n",d1.numerator,d1.denominator);

    gcd= find_gcd(d1.numerator, d1.denominator);

   printf("In lowest terms: %d/%d",d1.numerator/gcd,d1.denominator/gcd);
}

int find_gcd(struct fraction s1, struct fraction s1)
{
    int remainder=0;

    while (s1.denominator !=0)
    {
        remainder = s1.numerator/s1.denominator;
        s1.numerator= s1.denominator;
        s1.denominator= remainder;
    }

    return s1.numerator;        //this is the gcd
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
GCD_structures.c:8:50: error: redefinition of parameter 's1'
 int find_gcd(struct fraction s1, struct fraction s1);
                                                  ^
GCD_structures.c:8:30: note: previous definition of 's1' was here
 int find_gcd(struct fraction s1, struct fraction s1);
                              ^
GCD_structures.c: In function 'main':
GCD_structures.c:20:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'find_gcd'
     gcd= find_gcd(d1.numerator, d1.denominator);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `find_gcd` is taking structures, but you are passing it `int`s... Read the error! It is printing it for *you*.

Comment: How are you suppose to differentiate between the first and second parameter if they're both named `s1`?

Comment: Thanks, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Your [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) algorithm is bust (even when you sort out the argument list).  For example, given 1 and 1, it doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 0):

in the signature of the function, both of the parameters are named `s1`

Fix that, perhaps by renaming one of the parameters to `s2`